# Date diff on a single column based on a "status" in SQL Server

Tags: datediff

I have a list of users by email and their status.
ID| Datetime |       Status       Email
| 2/19/2024 6:30 |             |john.com
| 2/19/2024 07:00| Available|   |john.com
| 2/19/2024 07:30 Available  |
2/19/2024 09:30|    Unavailable
2/19/2024 10:30 |   Available.

The desired output for each user is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cvFe.png)
Using SQL SERVER

The problem I have is calculating Total Unavailable status with datediff because as shown above the user went unavailable at 9:30 and available at 10:30 for a difference of 60 minutes. A user can go Unavailable to Available many times so it like capturing those data pairs.

I have tried subquery, case statements, I tried flagging rows to be grouped. The essence of the issue is that the dates are all in one column and the status is the only thing that changes.  I need to be able to calculate the date difference from rows that are marked unavailable to available for many users in a single table. I need a total summary as shown in my expected results.  Thoughts?

Temp tables do not seem to help because I need the unavailable to available pair to be on a single row, several times as needed for each user. I am not and expert so any direction would be great.

| email | starttime | endtime | total_available hours | total unavailable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john doe | 02/01/07:00 | 02/01/2024 5:00 10 hours ?????? |  |  |
| jane | Cell 4 |  |  |  |

I can already calculate everything but total unavailable.  because not able to capture the unavailable / available pairs in for each user in the date.  Will this take some advanced scripting of some type?

Comment: Please read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask